# How to add specific SharePoint Group to List permission with c#?

Tags: development, permissions, object-model

```
using (SPSite site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent)
{
   using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
   {
        if (web != null)
        {
          web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
          SPList list = web.Lists["Alert Status v1.0"];

          //Creates a new role assignment for a group
          SPGroup myGroup = web.SiteGroups["IKM Manager"];
          SPRoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignments = web.RoleAssignments;

          // SPRoleAssignment accepts a SPPrincipal which can be a SPUser or SPGroup
          SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(myGroup);

          //Add the new role assignment to the collection of role assignments for the site.
          roleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);

          // Stop inheriting permissions
          list.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
          list.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
          list.Update();
```

I have error on RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment) like "Cannot add a role assignment with empty role definition binding collection". I want to stop inheriting permissions and add specific group to List permissions. Can you help me? please..

Comment: Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the role (as in what level of permission to grant the group).

The class is `SPRoleDefinition`.

```
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(myGroup);
SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Administrator);
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
roleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358647/programatically-add-user-permission-to-a-list-in-sharepoint

Comment: thank you for your answer but normally I have IKM Manager group which is in root site permission, has Full Control. My list is inheriting permissions. I want to stop inheritance and set the just IKM Manager group to my list. So, I need to know that do I have to set roledefinition to this group? because it is defined already!!

Comment: I updated my post to reflect this. It's two lines of code between your two lines. `SPRoleType.Administrator` is Full Control in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to use `list.BreakRoleInheritance(false)`. Using true copies the existing role assignments to the list - so everyone who had access to the site would continue to have access to the list. Using false clears any role assignments - so nobody has any access, until you add your new one.

2) As mentioned above, you have to use a [Role Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproledefinition_members) to assign how much access a particular Role Assignment provides.

```
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Administrator));
```

The [SPRoleType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproletype.aspx) enumeration provides a shortcut to the predefined permissions levels. You can also set rights individually for a Role Definition using it's [BasePermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproledefinition.basepermissions).